# Exception Specification causing trouble while inheriting a class from an interface and abstract class

Tags: java, exception

```
interface A{
    void f() throws FillInStack;
}
abstract class Abs{
    abstract public void f() throws MyExc;
}
class interface_excep extends Abs implements A{
    @Override
    public void f(){   }  
}
```

Above code compiles with no error.
**FillInStack** and **MyExc** are simple classes derived from **Exception**

I have even used **function f()** in two different exception cases that gives no error...

1st Case:

```
A a=new interface_excep();
try{
    //...
    a.f();
}
catch(FillInStack m){ 
    //...
}
```

2nd Case:

```
Abs a=new interface_excep();
try{
    //...
    a.f();
}
catch(MyExc m){ 
    //...
}
```

But when I tries to throw exception from the function **f()** it gives error.

```
public void f() throws MyExc{ //! Error
    //...
    throw new MyExc();
    //...
}
```

I know that changing name of method f() from both interface A and abstract class Abs will solve the problem. But what if I Derive my class from an interface and  abstract class provided to me by some vendor library and got into the similar situation, then how will I throw any exception from this function???

Does Java have any implicit solution for this or simply we must have two function with different name???

**Edit:**

Code for the above two exception...

```
class MyExc extends Exception{  }
class FillInStack extends Exception{   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `f` has two different signatures, you are in crazy-land trying to inherit both versions. When you declared `A a=new interface_excep();` (non-compliant type name!) you tell the compiler that `a` is of type `A`, which is why it recognizes that exception toss in the `catch`. Likewise with `Abs a=new interface_excep();` (non-compliant type name!) you tell the compiler that `a` can throw the other exception. But when you try to define `public void f() throws MyExc` in a class that inherits both `A` and `Abs`, you're adding a restriction that `A` does not recognize, which violates the override regulations. So you can't do that, nor can you override it to throw `FillInStack` because that violates the contract from `Abs`. So you can (and actually must) catch either exception, depending on the compile-time type of the variable, but you can never throw either one.

You've intentionally set up incompatible contracts so that no implementing class can fulfill both. So no, you won't get away with that.

Per the Liskov Substitution Principle, any subtype must fit where its supertype does. That means the override can declare fewer `throws` exceptions, but never more than its supertype. So you either need to fix up the interface to allow both exceptions, or forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the fact that `A` and `Abs` both have a method named `f` fool you into thinking that they are the same method. Since `Abs` does not implement `A` then they are two completely different methods that coincidentally have the same name. Once you realize that, then this is easy. I assume you are asking because you want to use `Abs` to implement `A` and that you can't modify either. Instead of using inheritance, you can use composition and the adapter pattern. Since `Abs` is abstract, we'll just have to add another layer:

```
public class Concrete extends Abs {
   // Implement any abstract methods from Abs here
}

public AbsToAAdapter implements A {
   private final Abs abs;

   public AbsToAAdapter(Abs abs){
      this.abs = abs;
   }

   // Override f from interface A
   @Override
   public void f() throws FillInStack {
      try {
         abs.f();
      } catch (MyExc ex){
         throw new FillInStack(ex); // Assuming FillInStack has constructor that takes a Throwable as its cause
      }
   }
}

public class ClassThatUsesA {

   public static void main(String[] args){
      A a = new AbsToAAdapter(new Concrete());
      try {
        a.f();
      } catch (FillInStack ex){
         // Handle ex
      }
   }
}
```

Again, this assumes that you don't have control of any of the classes in question. You do have more options when you control the classes. Namely, `Abs` can extend `A` and `MyExc` can extend `FillInStack`.

This may seem like a lot, but if the two methods had different names then you wouldn't think twice about an approach like this. It's also the only choice here because `Abs.f` and `A.f` have no relationship whatsoever to each other.